# error in open cv application "the application failed to initilize propely (0x0000005). click ok to terminate the program"

Tags: opencv, mingw, codeblocks

im using code::blocks IDE and mingw 4.7.2 compiler. resently i installed open cv 2.4.5 when i build the following program it build without errors. but when starting the progrm it terminates giving the error

`the application failed to initilize propely (0x0000005). click ok to terminate the program`

all the librarys are linked properly, and all the nessory directoris are added to the path variable. the program is a very simple program that just reads a image and displays it. eny ideas how to avoid this error. thanks for eny help....

here when i tested the exe in dependency walker

[image]

it says `dwmpi.dll` is missing. what may be gone wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) utility to be sure your program is not missing any .dll files.

Comment: here i updated my question and added the dependency walker results. please help...

Comment: then i downloaded that dll from the internet and placed it next to my program, but the problem was not solved